# Why does this python code errors in Google Colab and works on Jupyter NB?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Said code:

```
def max_displacement():
    daily_climb = [30, 21, 33, 77, 44, 45, 23, 45, 12, 34, 55]
    displacement_lst = []
    
    for x in daily_climb:
        if x > 20:
            diff = (x - 20)
            displacement_lst.append(diff)
            
    
    return max(displacement_lst)
   
solution2 = max_displacement()
print(solution2)
```

Don't understand the error on Google colab saying:

[Error on Google Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kud8Y.png)

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: The error is saying that `displacement_lst` is an empty list when `max(displacement_lst)` is trying to run. Are you sure you're running the very same code in Colab? Nothing overwriting `max_displacement` function?

Comment: @MariaK, no, the error message is saying that ```max()``` must receive no arguments, but one argument was given. There is probably another function binded to the name "max", overriding Python built-in ```max()``` function.

Answer (score 3):

You probably defined max as a function somewhere before in google colab.

search for "def max".

When you do that you override the default max function that python provides. Your function takes no argument. And you give it an argument.

Comment: A good way to confirm what's going on would be to `help(max)`, or given those environments `?max` would likely work as well